# O que significam estes pontos de interrogação?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

O que significam os pontos de interrogação nesse `get`.

O que significam `int?` e `??` nesta linha de código, já encontrei exemplos que utilizavam `?` e `??` mas nunca tantos numa única linha e isto faz um pouco confusão.

```
 public int Something
 {
    get { return (this.parameters["Loading"] as int?) ?? 1; }
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O ponto de interrogação aqui `int?` significa que sua variável do tipo inteiro aceita valores nulos, enquanto o `??` significa que caso retorno de `(this.parameters["Loading"] as int?)` seja nulo, set o mesmo com 1, é uma condição, caso o retorno seja nulo set o mesmo com 1.

Answer (score 4):

Significa que se o valor de

```
this.parameters["Loading"]
```

for nulo o retorno será 1.